# C# - Static Member only operate on static data?

Tags: c#

From MSDN document i understand ( I am not sure,i understand perfectly ) :

Static members can operate only on static data and call static methods of the

defining class.

---

I worked out the following code :

```
class Test
{
 static int i;

 public static void StaticDemo()
 {
  int v;
  i=10;
  v=10*i;  

  Console.WriteLine("The value of i={0}",v);

 }
}
```

In the above example the declaration  **int v  *inside the method StaticDemo( )*  is not static field. Then how did the operation v = 10 * i  work ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MSDN documentation refers to the fact that you **cannot access instance members** within a static method if you don't pass in an instance. Of course, every method **can declare local variables** and use them.

Answer (score 5):

The `int v` is local to the function, and therefore not a class member as such. (I.e. it doesn't need an instance of the class)

Answer (score 3):

Functions can always operate on local variables irrespective of whether they are static. Since v is declared within your StaticDemo function it is a local variable (i.e. only accessible within the function).

What the documentation is referring to is that you cannot access instance variables within a static method.  So if instead of declaring i as 'static int i;' you had declared it as 'int i;' the StaticDemo method would not have been able to access it, since it would be an instance variable (i.e. not static).

Answer (score 2):

Because `v` does not belong to the **defining class** but to the **method** and thus can be operated on by the method.

Answer (score 1):

It works because v is local to the static function itself.  If v was defined in the body of the Test class, it would not.

Answer (score 1):

Because variables defined *inside* a method are not either static or instance... They are locally scoped to the *method itself*.

They are stored in the method's stack frame, and have nothing to do either with the instance, or with the class.

Answer (score -1):

Because it doesn't have any scope beyond the static method. In other words, there is no state being kept on the method

Comment: It's not private.  It's local.